# IPad Textfield DropDown with PopOver Control

Tags: xcode, ipad, drop-down-menu, popover

Im wanting to create a generic dropdown control for my IPad app. Basically when the user clicks on a textfield a popover control will show and list items. The users can keep typing in the textfield which will filter the items in the dropdown popover control.

Has anyone got any advice or know of any examples on accomplishing this?

Basically it will be like the "Suggestions" popover list in the App store search field of the ipad.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would accomplish this by loading a **TableViewController** into the **PopoverController** and make its interface  available to the **ViewController** (the one that has the textfield in it).

In the **TableViewController** I would load a dictionary/array of items. Whenever a user enters text in the textfield (you can respond on this trough events in your Interface Builder) I would then call a function in the **TableViewController** that updates the list that is displayed (e.g. displays all dictionary items that start with the entered text).

Whenever someone clicks on a item in **TableViewController**, you can then call a function in the **ViewController**.

I can't give you a code sample, since that would require quite some time to create :P.

I hope this helps you.